# Scripting PowerShell benchmark commands

Tags: python, powershell

first i want to say that i am not that much into coding.
The only language i learned is a little bit of python, just the basics.

I want to make my work easier and automate some tasks i have to do manually now.

**The Problem:**

Sometimes i have to create a benchmark of some workstation PC´s of our customers.
I realise this with:

> powershell -> winsat disk -v
>
> powershell -> winsat cpuformal -v
>
> powershell -> winsat memformal -v
>
> powershell -> winsat graphicsformal -v
>
> powershell -> winsat dwmformal -v

So i start powershell with Admin rights and type in the first command, wait for the result and copy+paste it to a .txt file.
Then the next and the next etc.

**My Question:**

How do i:

Open PowerShell with administrator rights from a script
Type in the command and execute it (like "print winsat disk...")
Wait for the results to show up and copy paste them to a .txt

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the WMI system has a class that stores that data. [*grin*] you can call it and either use the resulting object directly OR build one that has only what you want.

what it does ...

- uses the CIM stuff to access the WinSAT info  for the designated system
- calcs the average of the ratings
- builds a `PSCustomObject` to hold that info
- displays the info

the code ...

```
$CIM_WinSAT = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_WinSAT -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME

$Average_WinSAT = ($CIM_WinSAT.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_ -match 'score'}).Value |
    Measure-Object -Average).Average

$WinSAT_Info = [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = $CIM_WinSAT.PSComputerName
    Perf_WinExp_Average = '{0:N2}' -f $Average_WinSAT
    Perf_WinExp_All = $CIM_WinSAT.WinSPRLevel
    Perf_WinExp_CPU = $CIM_WinSAT.CPUScore
    Perf_WinExp_RAM = $CIM_WinSAT.MemoryScore
    Perf_WinExp_Disk = $CIM_WinSAT.DiskScore
    Perf_WinExp_Vid = $CIM_WinSAT.GraphicsScore
    Perf_WinExp_Vid_D3D = $CIM_WinSAT.D3DScore
    }

$WinSAT_Info
```

output ...

```
ComputerName        : [MySysName]
Perf_WinExp_Average : 7.02
Perf_WinExp_All     : 6.5
Perf_WinExp_CPU     : 7.3
Perf_WinExp_RAM     : 7.3
Perf_WinExp_Disk    : 7.5
Perf_WinExp_Vid     : 6.5
Perf_WinExp_Vid_D3D : 6.5
```

Comment: This is very helpfull, thank you alot.  I will try it by times.

Comment: @alias42 - you are quite welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> import os
>
> os.system("""powershell -command "winsat disk -v" >> result.txt """)
>
> os.system("""powershell -command "winsat cpuformal -v" >> result.txt """)

You can try running this script using administrator. Reference [here](https://pyfourm.com/posts/post/powershll-and-cmd-using-python/)